Access specific tag within nested tags of an XML file in Java
I have the following XML :
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://...." xmlns:web="http://...">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <web:ComponentExecutorExecuteRequest>
         <web:group></web:group>
         <web:payload><![CDATA[<SSC>
    <SContext>
        <BusinessUnit>E01</BusinessUnit>
    </SContext>
    <Payload>
        <Filter>
            <Expr operator="AND">
                <Item name="/Ledger/Line/AccountingPeriod" operator="EQU" value="0122023" />
                <Item name="/Ledger/Line/AccountCode" operator="EQU" value="262222150" />
                <Item name="/Ledger/Line/TransactionDate" operator="BETWEEN" minvalue="23012024" maxvalue="23012024" />
            </Expr>
        </Filter>
        <Select>
            <Ledger>
                <Line>
                    <AccountCode></AccountCode>
                    <AccountingPeriod></AccountingPeriod>
                </Line>
            </Ledger>
        </Select>
    </Payload>
</SSC>]]>
        </web:payload>
      </web:ComponentExecutorExecuteRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>


I want to iterate over the property 'Expr' to be able to access the  elements so I can assign the properties dynamically, this is the code I currently have in Java:

private String generarPayload(String accountingPeriod, String accountCode,
String transactionDateInicio, String transactionDateFin, String token)
throws Exception {
    Document doc = null;
    doc = utiles.loadXMLFromResource("/com/..Siniestro.xml");

    NodeList items = doc.getElementsByTagName("Item");

    for (int j = 0; j < items.getLength(); j++) {

        Node tmp = items.item(j);

        if (tmp.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            NamedNodeMap atributos = tmp.getAttributes();
            
            if (atributos.getNamedItem("name").getNodeValue().equals("/Ledger/Line/AccountingPeriod")) {
                
                if (accountingPeriod.equals("")) {
                    tmp.getParentNode().removeChild(tmp);
                } else {
                    atributos.getNamedItem("value").setNodeValue(accountingPeriod);
                }
            }

            if (atributos.getNamedItem("name").getNodeValue().equals("/Ledger/Line/AccountCode")) {
                if (accountCode.equals("")) {
                    tmp.getParentNode().removeChild(tmp);
                } else {
                    atributos.getNamedItem("value").setNodeValue(accountCode);
                }
            }

            if (atributos.getNamedItem("name").getNodeValue().equals("/Ledger/Line/TransactionDate")) {
                if (transactionDateInicio.equals("") || transactionDateFin.equals("")) {
                    tmp.getParentNode().removeChild(tmp);
                } else {
                    atributos.getNamedItem("minvalue").setNodeValue(transactionDateInicio);
                    atributos.getNamedItem("maxvalue").setNodeValue(transactionDateFin);
                }
            }
        }
    }


However the result of the variable 'items' is an empty list, so it does not enter the for and much less the ifs  as if it does not exist in the xml, could you tell me what am I doing wrong?


Yeah, your <Item> elements are inside a <![CDATA[ ... ]]> which means that the XML parser sees them as text, not as elements.  You'll have to extract the <![CDATA[ ... ]]> content and parse it separately.

This should help. It prints the XML inside CDATA. You have to parse it separately -
Document doc = null;
        doc = loadXMLFromResource("soap.xml");
        String cdataValue = doc.getDocumentElement()
                .getElementsByTagName("soapenv:Body").item(0)
                .getChildNodes().item(1) // web:ComponentExecutorExecuteRequest
                .getChildNodes().item(3) //[web:payload: null]
                .getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
        System.out.println(cdataValue);

        DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document doc1 = docBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(cdataValue)));
        System.out.println(doc1.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes().item(1));

